# How to make Poisson voronoi diagram

Tags: computational-mathematics

I am facing a problem as follows : I want to make poisson voronoi diagram & for this I have to appropriately choose some generating points. Sources on internet(WIKI) refers that these points have to be obtained from poisson processes. So, how can I go about doing this in Mathematica? 
[I have little exposure to Poisson processes or for that matter any other process.]

Comment: The idea is relatively simple: in two dimensions, if you have a square region, split it into "cells", associate each cell with a Poisson-distributed random integer (call it $k$), and generate $k$ points in that cell with the coordinates drawn from a uniform distribution.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. could you please elaborate a bit more on creation of "cells".

Comment: You just cut the square into $n\times n$ smaller squares, for some $n$.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. then what are u trying to convey via 'generate k points'. k is the name to denote the RV(that's what I got). Please clarify

Comment: The output of `RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[(* stuff *)]]` is an integer, right? That is the number of points you need to generate in the cell that number is associated with.

Comment: It seems that this question isn't really about Mathematica but about understanding what "Poisson process" means, especially in 2D.

Answer (score 2):

```
vMesh = VoronoiMesh[
   myPts = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], 50]];
Show[vMesh, Graphics[Point /@ myPts]]
```

[image]